# Android Studio - How to get value from FireBase Realtime Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform

I want to get data from the Firebase Realtime Database.

[Here is my database format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HtiIO.png)

I'm trying to access the value of "creator" by giving the user's Email.

For example:

For the input cc@cc@cc I will get false.

For the input tt@tt@tt I will get true.

Here is my code:

```
String key = emailEditText.getText().toString().replace(".","@");
myRef.child("Users").child(key).child("creator").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                                    try {
                                        for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                                            if(postsnapshot.getValue().equals(true)){
                                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,CreatorActivity.class));
                                                
                                            }
                                            else
                                                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this,WelcomeActivity.class));

                                        }
```

*Key is the Input Email.

Comment: OK, you posted what you want to do and some code. Now ... what is your _question_? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hello, My question is how to access the firebase value from the android studio. I'v posted here my code to access but it dosent work @dominicoder

Comment: You already have code. Does it not work? If not, why not? What have you done to solve this and and what - exactly - is not working? Have you read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: While @alexmamo has a terrific answer, the bigger picture is... don't use email addresses as node keys. They can contain illegal characters which you have to deal with (as you know) and most importantly, email addresses can change... Node keys cannot be changed and email addresses can change; if that happens you'll have to go through your *entire database* and read in, delete and re-write every node where that was used as a key, or *referenced*. That can get very expensive and a time suck. Better bet is to let Firebase create your node keys, and store the email address as a child node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String email = "cc@cc.cc";
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = db.child("Users");
Query queryByEmail = usersRef.orderByChild("email").equalTo(email);
queryByEmail.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (DataSnapshot ds : task.getResult().getChildren()) {
                boolean creator = ds.child("creator").getValue(Boolean.class);
                Log.d("TAG", "creator: " + creator);
            }
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
creator: false
```

However, if you change the email to:

```
String email = "tt@tt.tt";
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
creator: true
```

This solution will work for multiple nodes in your database. If you only want to check a single one, then please use the following line of code:

```
String email = "cc@cc@cc";
DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference creatorRef = db.child("Users").child(email).child("creator");
creatorRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DataSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DataSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.getResult()
            boolean creator = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            Log.d("TAG", "creator: " + creator);
        } else {
            Log.d("TAG", task.getException().getMessage()); //Don't ignore potential errors!
        }
    }
});
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
creator: false
```

However, if you change the email to:

```
String email = "tt@tt@tt";
```

The result in the logcat will be:

```
creator: true
```